# how to get combobox text in java script from jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to pass the test in the combobox to another page as included in query string using JavaScript

```
<select name="classn" id="classnId" onchange="populate()" > 
<option value="select">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">I Class</option>
<option value="2">II Class</option>
<option value="3">III Class</option>
```

here is the populate function

```
function populate(){
            $.ajax({url:"getbatchno.jsp?itid="+$('#classnId').val(),success:function(result){

                }});}
```

but using the above Script I am able to pass only the value part of combobox and I need to pass the text also(I Class,II Class,... etc).

Comment: You sent the text to the browser in the first place. You should be able to use the number in the value to determine what it is on the server. There's no need to send it back to the server.

Comment: $('#classnId option:selected').text()

Comment: Thaks you  @Murali it really helped to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get text of selected option with jQuery you could use that:

```
 $('#classnId option:selected').text();
```